# Как сделать селект с table type Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Объявление типа:

```
TYPE tp_loan IS RECORD(
id                             mc_account.id%TYPE,
colvir_id                      mc_account.colvir_id%TYPE,
iban                           mc_account.iban%TYPE,
nearest_pay_date               DATE,
nearest_pay_amount             NUMBER(38));

TYPE tp_loan_list IS TABLE OF tp_loan INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

Заполнение type:
t_loan_list          tp_loan_list;

```
select ac.id,
ac.colvir_id,
ac.iban,
pkg_mb_model_credit.get_nearest_pay_date(ac.colvir_id),
pkg_mb_model_credit.get_nearest_pay_amount(ac.colvir_id)
bulk collect into t_loan_list
from mc_account ac
where ac.iban = r_account.repay_account
AND ac.smodule <> '01'
AND ac.mc_agreement_id = r_agreement.id
AND ac.status = 1
AND ac.access_level >= n_access_level;
```

Как сделать селект с этого типа?:

```
select sum(t.nearest_pay_amount)
from TABLE(t_loan_list) t
where (t.nearest_pay_date < r_account.next_pay_date
OR (t.nearest_pay_date = r_account.next_pay_date
AND t.id < i.id));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если типы локальные в скелетах их использовать не получиться, для использования в выборке могут использоваться только созданные типы данных

Comment: Расшифровываю :) ответ от @РавшанАбдулаев. 
В select можно использовать SQL типы, созданные командой CREATE TYPE. А у вас типы PL/SQL.